# Dataframe has string column with date values in different formats. how to convert entire column data to single date format?

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

converting string to datetime in python pandas with multiple date formats in a column.

Dataframe startdate has date values in 'mm-dd-YYYY hh:mm' format and 'mm/dd/YYYY hh:mm' format.
I have used following query

```
  df['START_DATE*'] = pd.to_datetime(df['START_DATE*'], format= '%m-%d-%Y hh:mm')
```

START_DATE* is the column name .giving following

> time data '01-01-2016 21:11' does not match format '%m-%d-%Y hh:mm' (match)

Comment: `%m-%d-%Y hh:mm` is not a valid format, it should be `%m-%d-%Y %H:%M`

Answer (score 3):

`hh:mm` does not mean `hour:minute`. Try:

```
df['START_DATE*'] = pd.to_datetime(df['START_DATE*'], format= '%m-%d-%Y %H:%M')
```

Comment: That won't be sufficient if the OP also has mm/dd/YYYY hh:mm formatted timestamps